# Windows Ubuntu: "no such file or directory" message when running from .bash_profile file but not from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So using windows bash I have created a .sh file (passwords.sh located in ~/../) which I ran the following commands on:

```
chmod 600 passwords.sh
sudo shown toot:root passwords.sh
```

Then in my .bash_profile (loacted in home folder ~/) I have the following function

```
function passwords {
     case "1$" in
          'update')
               'sudo vim ~/../passwords.sh';;
           *)
               'sudo bash ~/../passwords.sh';;
     esac
}
```

Running the command directly from the terminal yeilds no problems;

```
ruben@DESKTOP-4RTTB0B:/home$ sudo bash ~/../passwords.sh
[sudo] password for ruben:
[content displayed as intentionally]
ruben@DESKTOP-4RTTB0B:/home$ sudo vim ~/../passwords.sh
[open with vim editor]
```

but running the new function yeilds

```
ruben@DESKTOP-4RTTB0B:/home$ passwords
-bash: sudo bash ~/../passwords.sh: No such file or directory
ruben@DESKTOP-4RTTB0B:/home$ passwords update
-bash: sudo vim ~/../passwords.sh: No such file or directory
```

Why does it work in the terminal but not from the .bash_profile file? Other similiar funcions in the .bash_profile file works fine. Thanks for all help^^

Comment: Probably `sudo shown` must be `sudo chown` (change owner).

Comment: you probably mean ```"$1"```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to quote a command. Write it thus:

```
function passwords {
     case "$1" in
          'update')
               sudo vim ~/../passwords.sh;;
           *)
               sudo bash ~/../passwords.sh;;
     esac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, the tilde `~` wont be expanded in any kind of quote marks. So, you need to change the relevant lines in this way:

```bsh
sudo vim ~'/../passwords.sh';;
```

Or better:

```bsh
sudo vim "$HOME/../passwords.sh";;
```

And why not (in this case) using full path instead of relative one:

```bsh
sudo vim "/home/passwords.sh";;
```

The quotation within a command is used in order to delimit the values of the positional parameters of the command, otherwise you need to escape each white space or any other special character:

```bsh
command 'first positional parameter' 'second one' "$THE_THIRD" our\ forth\ parameter
```

Note, most shells will expand the variables only within double quote marks, within single quote marks the name of the variable will be treat as string and wont be expanded.